# The relation between App.vue and Other component at Vuejs webpack

Tags: vue.js

I installed vuejs with webpack.

```
vue init webpack frontend
```

And I use vue-router at main.js

```
routes: [
  {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: HomeView
  },
```

App.vue is like here.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id='toparea'></div>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <div id='btmarea'></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

file structure here

[image: file structure here]

Is the relation of App.vue and HomeView.vue patent-child relation ?
How can I use App.vue's data at HomeVuer.vue?

More specific:

I printed a variable at App.vue like this.

```
<div id='toparea'>
    <span v-html="variable_foo"></span>
</div>
```

And I want to change at HomeView.vue at HomeView.vue's mounted step.

Comment: Just an FYI, the new `@vue/cli` v3 is much better than than v2 (the one you're using)

Comment: This question is a little too broad for StackOverflow but in general... _"Is the relation of App.vue and HomeView.vue parent-child"_ <- no, they are completely decoupled via the router. _"How can i use App.vue's data at HomeVuer.vue"_ <- the typical approach is to use a state management library like Vuex

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is it better to change the title? "How can i use App.vue's data at HomeVuer.vue under webpack default templete?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special relation between App.vue and HomeView.vue. App.vue is for root component. HomeView is one of your components for rendering page. This component will be rendered on `<router-view></router-view>`. If you register some components on router, you can see them through `router-view`.

To pass Props you can check this: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

Or you can use Vuex(https://vuex.vuejs.org/) for state management. App.vue and HomeView.vue can share their states with it.

Comment: This is exactly what i want to know. I solve the problem using vuex. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I found App.vue apparently is parent of HomeView.vue from vuejs devtool.

It means router view component is children of main app view component.

[image]